# unable to bind jboss to external ip address

Tags: networking, operating-system, jboss7.x

i am trying to bind jboss to an external ip address other than the default 127.0.0.1 but i am getting error and unable to.

The IP address that i want to bind to is valid and accessible and i have tested using ping. I have tried modifying the standalone.conf or modifying standalone.xml and also tried the -b xxx.xxx.236.237 approached but getting same error every time.

Need help please. thanks.

```
     ------- tried setting bind address in standalone.conf
       JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address.management=xxx.xxx.236.237"
        JAVA_OPTS="$%JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=xxx.xxx.236.237"

      ---- tried starting service with binding address
        standalone.sh -b xxx.xxx.236.237

    ---tried below changes in standalone.xml
   <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:xxx.xxx.236.237}"/>
    </interface>

   But i am able to bind it to 0.0.0.0 which i dont want to. i want to bind to specific ip.
```

18:18:15,122 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
18:18:15,142 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public
        at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:97) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind a process ONLY on one or all (0.0.0.0) of the ip addresses of YOUR (the host that runs JBOSS) host network interfaces

To see you network interfaces ip addresses.

Under linux see:

```
ifconfig -a
```

or

```
ip addr show
```

Comment: i guess i get it. i can only bind to an address which I see in ifconfig. i was trying an external ip of my host but ifconfig showed me internal ip. able to bind to internal ip. thanks.

Comment: Manish if this is the answer you're looking for I appreciate if you flag me as solution. Cheers.